# PHP - Disable Required Field

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm trying really hard to figure out how to disable a required field. I've read things that just say too torn required_field to optional_field, but that didn't work. I tried changing the if, else statement but I don't think I'm doing it in the right place. Would someone care to learn me?

I know it's in one of the two sections below

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
 function died($error) {
      // your error code can go here
      echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
      echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
      echo $error."<br /><br />";
      echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
      // You can replace all of this with HTML.... dont forget that
      // as long as you keep the echo $error part
      die();
 }
 function clean_phone_number($string) {
      $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);
      $string = preg_replace('/[^0-9\-]/', '', $string);
      return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string);
 }
 function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
 }
 function required_field($field,$field_name){
      if($field == ""){
           died($field_name. " is a required Field!");
      }
 }

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
 $email_to = "mail1@example.com , mail2@example.com , mail3@example.com";
 $email_subject = "Wood Engraving Services - Order Quote";

 // validation expected data exists

 $error_message = "";
 //get fields, and check if they are filled
 $project_name = $_POST['project_name'];
 required_field($project_name,"Project Name");

 $email_from = $_POST['email'];
 required_field($email_from,"Email");

 $phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
 required_field($phone_number,"Phone Number");

 $wood_type = $_POST['wood_type'];
 required_field($wood_type,"Wood Type");

 $size = $_POST['size'];
 required_field($size,"Size");

 $attachment_file_link = $_POST['attachment'];

 $other_info = $_POST['other_info'];
 required_field($other_info,"Additional Info");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the call to

```
required_field();
```

below the field that you don't want to be required.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. I'll try it again!

Comment: `$attachment_file_link = $_POST['attachment'];` isn't required either so this should work.